# Discovering Ruby object members?

Tags: ruby, discoverability

What is an easy way to find out what methods/properties that a ruby object exposes?

As an example to get member information for a string, 
in PowerShell, you can do

```
"" | get-member
```

In Python,

```
dir("")
```

Is there such an easy way to discover member information of a Ruby object?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
"foo".methods
```

See:

http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html

http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Class.html

http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html

Comment: `"foo".methods - Object.methods` to be more specific

Answer (score 26):

Ruby doesn't have properties. Every time you want to access an instance variable within another object, you have to use a method to access it.

Comment: It's great to know that everything is a method.  Thanks Andrew

Answer (score 17):

Two ways to get an object's methods:

```
my_object.methods
MyObjectClass.instance_methods
```

One thing I do to prune the list of inherited methods from the Object base class:

```
my_object.methods - Object.instance_methods
```

To list an object's attributes:

```
object.attributes
```

Comment: #attributes is AR specific; for a plain ruby object there's #instance_variables. Also, you can pass false as an argument to #methods to skip inherited ones.

Comment: @noodl, thanks. I meant instance_variables, but have too much Rails in my head :)

Comment: Kind of old, but `instance_variables` doesnt seem to show uninitialized variables, was hoping it showed attributes set with `attr_accessor` or its cousins

Answer (score 9):

There are two ways to accomplish this:

`obj.class.instance_methods(false)`, where 'false' means that it won't include methods of the superclass, so for example having:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

p1 = Person.new 'simon'
p1.class.instance_methods false # => [:name, :name=]
p1.send :name # => "simon"
```

the other one is with:

```
p1.instance_variables # => [:@name]
p1.instance_variable_get :@name # => "simon"
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this:

```
my_object.instance_variables
```

Answer (score 2):

```
object.methods
```

will return an array of methods in object